# What does the notation $\alpha = \inf \{i > 0 : X_i > X_0 \}$ mean, where the $\{X_i\}_0^{\infty}$ are IID continuous?

Tags: notation, random-variables

I don't think I've seen this notation before $\alpha = \inf \{i > 0 : X_i > X_0 \}$. What does the colon here mean? What does this expression mean in words?

It seems we're assigning the variable $\alpha$ to the RHS, where the RHS is the infimum of a set of random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_{\infty}$ are IID continuous?

Comment: `:` can mean [such that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate), sometimes written `|` instead

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ah I see. I'm familiar with the vertical bar notation.

Answer (score 1):

For each $\omega\in\Omega$, $\alpha(\omega)$ is the minimum index $i$ such that $X_i(\omega)>X_0(\omega)$.

For example: If $X_0(\omega_0)=2$ and $X_1(\omega_0)=0.4$, $X_2(\omega_0)=1.3$, $X_3(\omega_0)=2.5$,... Then $\alpha(\omega_0)=3$.

Note: That is wrong defined. $X_i>X_0$ must be changed to $X_i\geq X_0$ (because can be the empty set with $>$)

Comment: Why is $i$ the minimum index?

Comment: @student010101 the set if indexes is closed, therefore the infimum and the minimum are the same..

Comment: There are two $>$s in the definition of $\alpha$. You probably mean the first one, which would be good to note explicitly

Comment: I edit for clarification

Comment: @CélioAugusto Isn't the set open because there is an infinite number of $X$'s?

Comment: Not necessarily. The index set could be the naturals (as @MartínVacasVignolo assumes it is), and the naturals form a closed set.